# Running Django without local server for testing purpose

Tags: python, django

I have installed Django on a local environment for test purpose.

How to run my project on HTTP without a local server?

Comment: `runserver` is [a server](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L58)? Not sure I understand your question

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make it more understandable for community.

Thanks.

Comment: @BHASHKAR I tried to rewrite your question but I am not sure of what you intended to ask (before, there was no real question, just a statement).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

This is page 1 of the introductory Django tutorial - work through it. Note the following sentence:

"...the Django development server, a lightweight Web server written purely in Python. We’ve included this with Django so you can develop things rapidly, without having to deal with configuring a production server – such as Apache – until you’re ready for production."